# How to build a PDF file under multiple threads document.close() performance?

Tags: java, itext

I build a PDF file under multiple threads and add some text with an embedded font(the font is True Type with a Unicode encoding).
My code snippet is below:

```
BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.createFont("/pathto/font.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font chineseFont = new Font(basefont, 14, Font.BOLD);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tmpfile);
Document doc = new Document(pdfReader.getPageSize(1), 50, 50, 50, 50);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baos);
pdfWriter.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);           
doc.open();
PdfImportedPage importPage = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
doc.newPage();
pdfContent.addTemplate(importPage, 0, 0);           
doc.add(new Paragraph("測試", chineseFont)); //chinese-characters
doc.close();            //**takes very long time**
```

But doc.close() takes very long time.
What is the problem?

```
at java/io/FileDescriptor.read(Native Method)
at java/io/FileDescriptor.read(FileDescriptor.java:73(Compiled Code))
at java/io/RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:319(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/RandomAccessFileOrArray.read(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:183(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/RandomAccessFileOrArray.readInt(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:482(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/TrueTypeFontSubSet.readLoca(TrueTypeFontSubSet.java:276(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/TrueTypeFontSubSet.process(TrueTypeFontSubSet.java:139(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/TrueTypeFontUnicode.writeFont(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:379(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontDetails.writeFont(FontDetails.java:280(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1251(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1173(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:830(Compiled Code))
at com/lowagie/text/Document.close(Document.java:495(Compiled Code))
```

Comment: **If** the time is indeed spent at `doc.close()`, then my gut tells me that it's I/O (flushing the data to disk).

Comment: I see that you are using `com.lowagie`, which is iText 2.1.7 or older, July 2009 or older. That version is no longer supported. Please reproduce your issue in a supported version: either 5.5.12 or 7.0.4.

Comment: You say you *build a PDF file under multiple threads*. 
If you really mean that multiple threads concurrently add content to the same `Document`, please be warned that iText is not designed for concurrent access to the same document. Thus, you must make sure that you properly synchronize the access.

Comment: Thanks for mkl, the snippet code is under a thread, so cann't add content to the same Document.

Comment: It can be many things: A huge file needs time to save. Maybe your machine doesn't have enough RAM or you have some locking/synchronization issues. With the code you provided it is hard to tell... Provide more code and one other option would be to use findbugs and check for any synchronization issues...